# поиск определенного tag в на сайте

Tags: java, html, парсер, search

Есть такая задача, необходимо найти опрделенный вид товара на сайте. Как это возможно сделать с помощью JAVA? А если конкретнее, то есть запрос на следующий вид стали - г X120Mn12 / 1.3401, диаметр: 130мм, кол-во: 500 кг, находиться эта позиция по следующему адресу - https://www.steelinox.nl/en/qualities/special-qualities/1.3401-a128-x120mn12. Задача в том, что поиск должен быть более менее универсальным для разных сайтов, с разной структурой. Аналогичную задачу для сайтов с прйсами в PDF, я зделал следующим образом, распарсил PDF-файл с помощью pdfbox в txt, а дальше ишу строку с наибольшим совпадением входящих аргументов (характеристики металла на разных сайтах (..или на разных производствах?) приводяться по разному). То есть я поиск я передаю String[] и link на PDF файл, результат получаю в виде List c переменной в которой содержиться количество совпадений в строек с переданным массивом STring[], соответсвенно строки с наибольшим показателем наиболее отвечаю клиентскому запросу. Вот что то, наподобие с html страницами, может кто посоветует, причем с html ссылка на конкретную страницу не пройдет, можно давать только ссылку на хост (адрес сайта), поскольку структура сайтов может быть различная. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы ваша программа сама находила нужный вам товар на указанно сайте, и при этом работала с другим сайтом. Мой вам совет - даже не беритесь за универсальность. Вы никогда не сможете даже предположить насколько криво сделан каждый новый сайт, и найти на нем что-то столько конкретное может быть вообще невозможно, потому что описание завернуто в картинку а в url просто id товара. Для одного конкретного сайта сделать то что вы хотите относительно просто, но чтобб это работало на любом сайте - близко к невозможному

Comment: ... да, определенные подозрения у меня уже появились, каждый сайт делается так, как кому-то удобно. И что-то универсально сделать не просто... Но может быть...